# In Javascript, how do I read multiple stream chunks from one API request using fetch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

In my Node/Express backend, I have a long (10 - 15sec) API call that sets up a user's account.

The call is triggered from my front-end by doing a simple `fetch('my/api/url')` GET request.

I'd like to be able to send messages to the frontend/my user about the status of the request. ("Setting up your profile", "Downloading your contacts", "Processing data" etc etc etc)

In my Express route, I'm (attempting) sending data via:

```
exports.setupAccount = async () => {
   res.write("Getting contacts");

   // A bunch of code and async awaits
   // and when it's done...
   res.write(`Retrieved ${contacts.length} contacts!`);
}
```

I'm trying to comprehend the [Mozilla Fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#Consuming_a_fetch_as_a_stream) at the moment and am not even sure if I'm looking in the right place.

In my frontend (just vanilla JS for now) I'm doing:

```
fetch('/my/setup/api')
.then(response => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  reader.read().then(async ({ done, value }) => {
    console.log("VALUE", value); // <== This returns a Uint8Array
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, value);
    console.log("Message from API:", str);
  })
})
```

This works, but only gives me the **first** `res.write()` sent from the server, and doesn't log out subsequent writes. How do I read multiple stream chunks using this `fetch`/`getReader()` method?

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer that works with vanilla JS, using a `while` loop with `await`:

```
fetch('/my/api')
.then(async response => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();

  while(true) {
    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
    // If it's done, there will be no value
    if (done) {
      console.log("Done!");
      break;
    }
    // value is Uint8Array of the chunk bytes
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, value);
    console.log(str)

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `response.text()` will read the stream to completion. We can also use the `Response` object to retrieve other formats like blobs (`response.blob()`) or json (`response.json()`) as well.

```
fetch('/my/setup/api')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => console.log("Message from API:", text))
```